# installation of kivy on anaconda or python 3.7

Tags: python, anaconda, kivy

I've installed anaconda and after that, I want to work on Kivy but whenever I try installing using this command:

```
$ conda install kivy -c conda-forge
```

I find this error:

```
Collecting package metadata: ...working... failed
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
```

I've tried it after installing python 3.7.4 also, but it shows error also.

Comment: python 3.7 has several compatibility issues with a few packages, I would recommend downgrading to 3.6.5 unless you really need something highly specific to 3.7